# \citeyear{} omits trailing character for citations from same date

Tags: biblatex, natbib

> **Bug in biblatex**

Well, I have this document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\bibliography{eva.bib}
\begin{document}
\citep{a}

\citep{b}

\citeyearpar{a}
\citeyearpar{b}
\end{document}
```

with A & B being published by the same author, in the same year. LaTeX produces:

> (title a, 1980a)
>
> (title b, 1980b)
>
> (1980)(1980)

I'd like to have the ordering character appended on the latter two year-citations. It's so simple, what am I missing?

Comment: It's unclear because you're using a custom style and citation command. But I'd guess in your definition of `\citeyearpar` you can use the starred variant `\citeyear*` to add `extrayear` in the citation label.

Comment: @Audrey: `citeyearpar`  is defined by `biblatex`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yeah, I forgot about natbib aliases. We should probably add `\citeyearpar*` in the next release.

Comment: @Audrey: I asked Joseph in the chat ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel OK. You can also post an issue at github. I'm actually not sure if natbib's `\citeyearpar` uses extrayear. If it does we should adopt your definition here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the definition of `\citeyearpar` in the file `blx-natbib.def`.

The definition is:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Here you can see that the field `extrayear` is missing. Based on this information you can modify the complete definition as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Next information related to your example. The command `\bibliography` is obsolete in combination with `biblatex`. The correct one is `\addbibresource`.

For the example below I am using the biblatex example file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%\bibliography{eva.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\verb+\citep{knuth:ct:a}+\qquad\citep{knuth:ct:a}

\verb+\citep{knuth:ct:c}+\qquad\citep{knuth:ct:c}

\verb+\citep{knuth:ct:d}+\qquad\citep{knuth:ct:d}


\verb+\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:a}+\qquad\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:a}

\verb+\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:c}+\qquad\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:c}

\verb+\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:d}+\qquad\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in `biblatex`: I'll discuss with PLK and Audrey.

Comment: @JosephWright Is this issue still open in `biblatex` 2.9a?

Comment: @Jörg @JosephWright Just to confirm that this problem persists in `biblatex` 2.9a. It would be great if you could get this fixed for 2015 Tex Live as this is a type of error that takes a long time to sort out if one doesn't know about it: Difficult to google and something that looks as if it were my own fault …