# How to get the lettering in \citeyear?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I have the following document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, language=french]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

When, for instance, I use the code:

```
\parencite{Boin2000} and \parencite{Boin2000b}
```

I get the following result:

> Boin, 2000a and Boin, 2000b

But when I use the code:

```
\citeyear{Boin2000} and \citeyear{boin2000b}
```

I only get:

> 2000 and 2000

Boin2000 and Boin2000b are related to the following .bib document:

```
@Book{Boin2000,
Title                    = {The Politics of Environment},
Author                   = {Boin, Mathis},
Publisher                = {Cambridge University Press},
Year                     = {2000},}
```

and

```
 @Book{Boin2000b,
 Title                    = {What is Environment},
 Author                   = {Boin, Mathis},
 Publisher                = {Environment Policies Review},
 Year                     = {2000},}
```

What should I do to also get the letters "a" and "b" that differentiate the two different references with \citeyear?

Comment: if your concerns have been addressed, you might consider accepting the answer that moewe gave you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `\citeyear` does not print the additional letter (the `extrayear` field) makes sense if you think about the application of the `\citeyear` command: It is used to write things like "In 2000 Foo finally succeeded in publishing the proof.", not to identify a citation; that is where other cite commands such as `\cite`, `\textcite` come in.

`\citeyear` has a starred variant `\citeyear*` that also prints the `extrayear`.
From the code this might lead to complications if the `labeldate` was not actually taken from `date` but from `origdate` (for example), then `extrayear` pertains to `origdate`, not to `date`, but the letter is affixed to `origdate`.

These first two solutions do not have hyper-linking enabled by default though.

You can suppress the mentioning of the author in `authoryear` and `authortitle` styles with **`\cite*`**. When using a `authoryear` style this effectively amounts to only printing the year (the `labelyear` actually) and `extryear` if need be.

If for some reason `\cite*` does not work (or has not been implemented in custom styles) and you are concerned about the corner case for `\citeyear*` I mentioned above, we can define it ourselves by

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelabelyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {\printfield{year}}
   {\printfield{labelyear}%
    \iffieldundef{extrayear}
      {}
      {\printfield{extrayear}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelabelyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {\printfield{year}}
   {\printfield{labelyear}%
    \iffieldundef{extrayear}
      {}
      {\printfield{extrayear}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
  \citeyear{knuth:ct:b} and \citeyear{knuth:ct:c}

  \citeyear*{knuth:ct:b} and \citeyear*{knuth:ct:c}

  \cite*{knuth:ct:b} and \cite*{knuth:ct:c}

  \citelabelyear{knuth:ct:b} and \citelabelyear{knuth:ct:c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, awesome, i totally read that wrong!

Comment: I use indeed hyperref, so \cite* does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I figured it'd be too long for a comment...

I really need a MWE like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109951/960) to know if this is a duplicate question or not.  Are you using biblatex and if so, what version?  There is a chance that your question has already been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67268/citeyear-omits-trailing-character-for-citations-from-same-date), which describes a bug that an update might fix.

If you're not using biblatex or that question does not apply to your situation, we at least need to see what your .bib contents for `boin2000` and `boin2000b` look like.  These are user defined labels, so I don't think they tell us very much, in and of themselves.

Edit:

I've been able to reproduce your problem with biblatex v2.9a using the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@Book{Boin2000,
Title                    = {The Politics of Environment},
Author                   = {Boin, Mathis},
Publisher                = {Cambridge University Press},
Year                     = {2000},}
@Book{Boin2000b,
Title                    = {What is Environment},
Author                   = {Boin, Mathis},
Publisher                = {Environment Policies Review},
Year                     = {2000},}
@Book{Anderson2003,
author      = {Anderson, John D.},
title       = {Modern Compressible Flow},
publisher   = {McGraw-Hill},
year        = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test}

\begin{document}
    My first citation should be \citeyear{Boin2000}, my second \citeyear{Boin2000b}, and my third \citeyear{Anderson2003}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: citationExample]

and reproduces your problem.  Asking around to see if this is still a bug in version 2.9a...

Comment: i originally tried to enter this as a comment, and with the code for the links, the character count was 666.  creepy.

Comment: Ok I have added the MWE as you asked. I tried to simplify at the maximum, so I hope nothing is missing. I also have checked the other topics, but it didn't seem to match.

Comment: This is actually not a bug, but expected behaviour. One needs to use other commands to also see the `extrayear`.